# Error while trying to make Camera Calibration using Charuco Board (OpenCV, C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, distortion, aruco

I'm trying to find distortion coeffitients using Charuco Board from the Aruco OpenCV library.
I'm using Qt and OpenCV libraries compiled for Qt.

First I've needed to do is to create the Charuco Board. I've done it using this:

```
    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;
    using namespace cv::aruco;

    ...

    Ptr<Dictionary> dictionary = getPredefinedDictionary(DICT_6X6_250);
    Ptr<CharucoBoard> board = CharucoBoard::create(5, 7, 0.04f, 0.02f, dictionary);
    Ptr<DetectorParameters> params = DetectorParameters::create();
    params->cornerRefinementMethod = CORNER_REFINE_NONE;
```

After that I have found Markers and Charuco Corners with its IDs on photos using `detectMarkers(...)` and `interpolateCornersCharuco(...)` functions.
I had 28 photos with the board or its parts.
Operation result looks like this (from 5 to 24 allocated corners per each image):

[Allocated Charuco Corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvyNH.png)

After that I tried to find Camera Matrix and Distortion Coeffitients using this:

```
    Mat cameraMatrix, distCoeffs;
    vector<Mat> rVectors, tVectors;
    double repError = calibrateCameraCharuco(allCharucoCorners, allCharucoIds, board, imgSize,
                                             cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rVectors, tVectors);
```

`allCharucoCorners` and `allCharucoIds` are vectors of vectors with equal size, `board` configured like shown above, `imgSize` got using function `cv::Size(loadedImg.cols, loadedImg.rows)`.

The program always tries to execute this function, but can not do it. Every time I try I have the project crash without any critical messages.

So maybe someone have an idea about what can be wrong?

Comment: What exactly is happening? How is it "crashing"?

Comment: you say "error". where's the error? show everything. make a debug build. use a debugger. ...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't said it. 
Under dubug I have information about signal from operating system, which coused crash:

Signal:  SIGSEGV
Appointment: Segmentation fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in OpenCV library.
Maybe it was badly compiled, or the problem is in the library itself.
I have used OpenCV version 4.5.3 before.
Then I compiled 4.5.4 version, and the program started to work well.